# Swift 検索機能

Tags: swift

Swiftにて検索機能の実装において

Tab Controllerに追加したViewController（SearchViewControroller）に以下のコードをもたせても data は containsString をもっていない とでてしまいます

どうしたらいいでしょうか？

追記

containsString をつかわない検索機能として filter というものもみたのですが どちらをつかったほうがいいでしょうか？

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewControroller: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testSearchBar: UISearchBar!

    let dataList: [String] = []

    //検索結果配列
    var searchResult = [String]()

    //最初からあるメソッド
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //デリゲート先を自分に設定する。
        testSearchBar.delegate = self

        //何も入力されていなくてもReturnキーを押せるようにする。
        testSearchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false

        //検索結果配列にデータをコピーする。
        searchResult = dataList
    }

    //データを返すメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchcell")!
        searchcell.textLabel?.text = dataList[indexPath.row]

    //データの個数を返すメソッド
    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return searchResult.count
    }



    //検索ボタン押下時の呼び出しメソッド
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        testSearchBar.endEditing(true)

        //検索結果配列を空にする。
        searchResult.removeAll()

        if(testSearchBar.text == "") {
            //検索文字列が空の場合はすべてを表示する。
            searchResult = dataList
        } else {
            //検索文字列を含むデータを検索結果配列に追加する。
            for data in dataList {
                if data.containsString(testSearchBar.text!) {
                    searchResult.append(data)
                }
            }
        }

        //テーブルを再読み込みする。
        testTableView.reloadData()
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

まず、tonyさんには、SwiftとXcodeを使って、ソフトウェア開発、プログラミングをする上で、身に付けておかなければならない知識がいくつかあります。質問に対する回答に入る前に、その必須な知識の話をさせてもらいます。

第一。プログラミング言語Swiftは、2014年に最初のバージョンがリリースされた、新しい言語です。そして2020年の今もまだ開発の途中であり、さまざまな拡張と改変を繰り返しています。拡張と改変には、細かなものも多数ありますが、ときに大規模な改変、180度方針転換した仕様変更がなされるときもありました。

`containsString(_ string: String)`

こういうメソッド名が

`contains(_ str: String)`

に変更されるということは、ざらにあることで、数年前に書かれたサンプルコードが、最新バージョンのXcodeでは、まったく通用しない、「containsString をもっていない」ということが生じます。
なので、初めて使うプロパティ、メソッドなどは、かならずXcode付属のドミュンメントと[リファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-contains)にあたる必要があります。英語の勉強をする時に、初めてみる英単語は、必ず英和辞書を引いてみるのと、同じことですね。

第二。Apple製品の開発言語の標準は、Swiftですが、2014年以前それはObjective-Cでした。Objeective-CがApple（以前のNext社の時代）の開発言語になったのが1985年のことですので、相当に古い言語といえます。が、iOSの基本フレームワーク（Foundation、UIKit）はこのObjective-Cで記述されており、SwiftによるiOSソフトウェアの開発は、Objective-Cとの互換性の上に成り立っています。

`let dataList: [String] = []`

のプロパティ宣言にあることから、

```
for data in dataList {
    if data.containsString(testSearchBar.text!) {
        searchResult.append(data)
    }
}
```

の箇所の変数`data`は、`String`型です。しかし、構造体`String`のリファレンスをいくら探しても、

`containsString(_ string: String)`も`contains(_ str: String)`というメソッドも見つかりません。このメソッドは、じつはクラス`NSString`にあります。`NSString`は、そもそもObjective-Cのクラスであって、Swiftの構造体`String`は、それと互換性があることを保証されています。

`if data.containsString(testSearchBar.text!)`

を

`if (data as NSString).contains(testSearchBar.text!)`

とすると、Xcodeの入力補完のリストに出てくるようになるでしょう。`as`は、型キャストを行う時に使う演算子です。

第三。Objective-CとSwiftの互換は、将来にわたって保証されているものではありません。現時点で、SwiftUIという、Objective-Cがまったく絡まない、Swift独自のフレームワークが実用化されようとしています。これからは、Swiftだけで完結するコード記述を前提にすることが必要になってくるでしょう。

> containsString をつかわない検索機能として filter というものもみたのですが どちらをつかったほうがいいでしょうか？

使うとしたら、プロトコル`StringProtocol`にある、

[func contains(_ other: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126753-contains)

を採用するべきでしょう。
「プロトコル」という言葉（というか概念）は、学習済みですか？もし初見だとしたら、Swift（じつはObjective-Cにおいても同様）の言語体系の根幹をなす、重要な概念なので、すこし腰を落ち着けて、じっくり学習すべきところです。
が、今回のご質問に即してみていくなら、プロトコルは、クラスや構造体などの型を構成する部品のようなものと、とらえる事ができます。正確ではありませんが、ひとつの面だけ見れば、そういう事ができます。
順を追って見ていきます。まず、文字列`"あいうえお"`に、文字列`"あい"`が含まれるか、調べたいと思います。それができる関数、メソッドがないか、探します。対象が文字列ですから、`String`型のメソッドにないか、リファレンスを探します。「含まれる」という意味の英単語になっているメソッドを探します。しかし、適当な物が見つかりません。次に、`String`のリファレンスの最後にある「Conforms To」（準拠している）に列挙してあるプロトコルをひとつひとつあたってきます。そうすると、プロトコル`StringProtocol`に、メソッド`func contains<T>(_ other: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol`というのが見つかりました。どうやらこれが使えそうです。構造体、クラスにないメソッドでも、準拠しているプロトコルにあるメソッドなら、その構造体でも、そのメソッドが使えるのです。

```
let aiueo = "あいうえお"
if aiueo.contains("あい") {
    print("Contains")
}
```

このような流れで、目的のメソッド、あるいはプロパティなどを見つけていくのです。

---

質問からは離れますが、一点だけ指摘しなければいけないところがあります。

`let dataList: [String] = []`

このようにプロパティを`let`で宣言してしまうと、要素数0の配列として固定されてしまい、なにをどうやっても要素数0から変更ができません。`let`と`var`の違いを、しっかり学習する必要があります。

Comment: たいへん適格なご周知ありがとうございます 

Protcolがいまいちわからないのでそのあたりをよくみてみます

Comment: やはりプロトコル（の概念）は読んでもわかりません

Comment: プロトコルは、抽象性が高い概念なので、説明を一回目を読んだだけで理解することは、いかなる天才でも無理です。数学と同様、手を動かしながら（式を実際に書いてみながら）でないと、理解はむずかしいでしょう。回答のほうに補筆をしました。それもご覧ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます 順の追い方をおしえていただき